# How do I filter a .json array in python so that only one parameter in each element shows?

Tags: python, arrays, json, api, filter

like the title says I'm having a problem filtering an array that I'm getting from the CoinGecko API. The array looks like this:

```py
[
  {
    "id": "01coin",
    "symbol": "zoc",
    "name": "01coin"
  },
  {
    "id": "0-5x-long-algorand-token",
    "symbol": "algohalf",
    "name": "0.5X Long Algorand Token"
  },
  {
    "id": "0-5x-long-altcoin-index-token",
    "symbol": "althalf",
    "name": "0.5X Long Altcoin Index Token"
  }
]
```

After the filter I'd like it to only show the "id"s like this:

```
[
  "01coin",
  "0-5x-long-algorand-token",
  "0-5x-long-altcoin-index-token"
]
```

This is how I tried to filter it:

```py
coinList = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list'
listCall = requests.get(coinList)
jsonCall = json.loads(listCall.content)
coinIds = [x for x in jsonCall if x == 'id']
```

Comment: You do it *the same* way that you would if you had gotten that data *in any other way*. It is *just* a list of dicts. Next, the way to answer "how do I get the result of doing something with each element of the list?" is: *figure out code that would do that thing to one element of the list*, and *then* put that in the list comprehension. So, the real question is: given *a dict* where one of the keys is `'id'`, how do you get the `'id'` value? And the answer is trivial: just look it up, like, `x['id']`.

Comment: There should not be `if` in the list comprehension, because *you want a result for every element of the list*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list comprehension is sort of there, but you should be indexing into each dictionary rather than using an `if` clause. It should look like:

```py
[item["id"] for item in jsonCall]
```

This outputs:

```py
['01coin', '0-5x-long-algorand-token', '0-5x-long-altcoin-index-token']
```